# Why the clear question was marked as unclear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Today I wrote the answer to an [one-line simple question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256366/magento-2-get-product-through-api-using-product-name/256386?noredirect=1#comment361064_256386) ("How to **get product through api using product name**" - which is totally clear for me) but some other people marked it as unclear. I cant understand how this one-line question can be unclear.

I pressed "reopen the question", but I can't understand by what these people are guided when they choosing a "close as unclear what you asking" on the totally clear question?

PS: Users who voted are not a newbies:

- [Manashvi Birla](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/26509/manashvi-birla) (6,084 rep)
- [Jai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/29175/jai) (3,375 rep)
- [Dhiren Vasoya](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/44220/dhiren-vasoya) (4,235 rep)
- [Murtuza Zabuawala](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/29731/murtuza-zabuawala) (12,290 rep)
- [Sukumar Gorai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/51003/sukumar-gorai) (6,265 rep)

Comment: Sorry bro, many times you don't spend much time to read the details and follow what others had done previously, I will try to focus more in review queue

Comment: Only thing that I would add is that the question is not really formatted as a question, and could therefore be marked as unclear. "I want to get product information using product name in Magento 2" is more like a statement than a proper question as such. Changing it to "How can I get product information using the product name in Magento 2?" would improve it slightly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Siarhey Uchukhlebau, Thanks for raising the concern.

Question is clear to me and also answer is OK. Now Question is Opened.

I guess that these people might do the mistake.

At some times, the people did the mistake on Harry. As a community member, I requesting all members to take your time to read the question and check what is the composition of the question and what would be the probable answers before creating the flag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can’t understand how 5 not-a-newbie persons can make a mistake at one time?

Comment: I cannot answer this question.Might be they can :)

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau I answer in your question about this

Answer (score 6):

This is sadly a common issue when people try to keep the site clean from unanswerable questions.
The Issue lies in Questions which are short and direct. If you know the context, that's sometimes a very easy to answer question.
But for someone who does not know the context, because they never worked in this area, they don't understand what the question is about and only see that it is very short and does not contain much information. They don't realise, there is no need for more information.